# 1970s (or older) book about a werewolf on an alien planet, who probably became one through alien technology

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, werewolf

I'm trying to remember then name of an old book I read as a kid, hope someone can help locate it?

Ok the book I read was part two of a trilogy from around the 70s maybe 80s, it starred a hero who was modified by some kind of either advanced tech or alien tech so that he could grow his fingernails and canine teeth when he needed to fight. I think his teeth were poisonous too, and I think he wore a ring that triggered this change somehow. The book was set on some alien planet with spaceships and so on, there was a part where an alien spaceship was found buried underground and the hero went to investigate it, I think there was some link to his power to transform found in this ship.

The cover of the book showed the hero piloting a spaceship with his teeth and "claws" extended and the ring on show on his finger. He wore a seventies looking sci fi helmet.

Um.. Honestly that's about all I can remember of it.. A bit vague I know.. Can anyone help? Does it sound familiar?

Answer (score 12):

I answered this [same question on another site earlier in the year](http://www.whatsthatbook.com/?xq=12075), took me a while to find my copies of the books and get the info posted.

It is a duo of books by Michael Kring.
*The Space Mavericks* (1980) is the first book, the second is called *Children of the Night* (1981) and it IS this second book whose cover you seem to remember.

[Fantasticfiction](http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/k/michael-kring/) has the bookcovers and small blurbs for the books. I've not been able to find anything on Wikipedia or an author website. Seems these were the only two books the author ever wrote.

Comment: Thank you! That was driving me nuts trying to remember :)